# Flink 1.9.1 Can no longer connect to Azure Event Hub

Tags: java, azure, apache-kafka, apache-flink, azure-eventhub

Java 8,
Flink 1.9.1,
Azure Event Hub

I can no longer connect to azure event hub with my flink project as of Jan 5th 2020. I was having the same issue with several spring boot apps but the issue was resolved when i upgraded to Spring Boot 2.2.2 which also updated Kafka Clients and Kafka dependencies to 2.3.1. I have attempted to update Flink's kafka dependencies without success. I've also submitted an issue

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-15557

> 2020-01-10 19:36:30,364 WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient -
>   [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=****] Bootstrap broker
>   *****.servicebus.windows.net:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected

Connection Properties

```
"sasl.mechanism"="PLAIN");
"security.protocol"="SASL_SSL");
"sasl.jaas.config"="Endpoint=sb://<FQDN>/;SharedAccessKeyName=<KeyName>;SharedAccessKey=<KeyValue>;EntityPath=<EntityValue>;
```

Comment: Have you tried contacting Azure support?

Comment: A ticket was submitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be using entity level connection string and that is why your clients are observing connection failures. The issue should resolve when namespace level connection string is used.

Comment: Updated with original connection properties as well as attempting the connection without the EntityPath

Comment: that fixed the issue. Do you know why the issue appeared on Jan 5th for a previously working connection at the entity level?

Comment: This was due to a security update to fail list-topic call with entity level connection string.